Flutter Background Service: Unable to Call Method Channel on Termination State
I'm developing a Flutter application that mutes the phone based on the user's location. I've successfully integrated Google Maps and other necessary components.
I'm utilizing the flutter_background_service package (https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_background_service) for my background service. However, I'm encountering an issue with communication between the service and native code for silencing the phone when app terminate.
While calling a Method Channel in foreground works perfectly from the Flutter UI thread, it fails when the service runs in the terminate state. My research indicates that Method Channels within the native MainActivity (Android) can only be invoked from the main isolate (Flutter UI).
My question: How can I effectively call a Method Channel when the app is in termination state?

I think when app is terminated it cannot invoke the method. You will have to register your app to run in the backgroud all the time for this.

@IKRAMULHAQ Do you have any code examples or references that might be helpful for this situation?
